# Query and exclude empty cells

Tags: google-sheets

I'm trying to query data, format it, and exclude empty cells.

[image]

```
=ARRAYFORMULA({"Date";IFERROR(QUERY({text(J2:J, "m/d/yyyy")}))})
```

Currently using this.

Tried using this:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA({"Date";IFERROR(QUERY({text(J2:J, "m/d/yyyy"), "where J <>''"}))})
```

But cells don't fill.

[image]

Not sure what I'm missing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you data in `J Column` are true date then you can use below `QUERY()` formula.

```
=QUERY(J2:J,"select J where J is not null label J 'Date' format J 'm/d/yyyy'")
```

> Edit: If data is string formatted then could try-

```
=ArrayFormula(QUERY(DateValue(J2:J),"select Col1 where Col1 is not null label Col1 'Date' format Col1 'm/d/yyyy'"))
```

[image]

Comment: It's staying the same format yyyy-mm-dd.

Comment: Then your data is not actual date. It is string. Can you share a copy your google-sheet here? So, that we can check it.

Comment: My data from column J is being pulled from another sheet.

Comment: I'm on mobile atm so it's a bit difficult. But this is the raw Dara cell =ARRAYFORMULA({"Raw Date";Query({IMPORTRANGE("1ueKBXZ766YDe4qR0NlSYt7fpJvsq6wET6pQktfUqVas","AutoRefresh!BG2:BG")})})

Comment: Then give a try on `=ArrayFormula(QUERY(DateValue(J2:J),"select Col1 where Col1 is not null label Col1 'Date' format Col1 'm/d/yyyy'"))`.

Comment: @cpaone I have edited answer. Please mark the answer as accepted (tick mark it) so that other can know it is solved.